# What is the default URL for a Java EE app running on Glassfish?

Tags: glassfish

Newbie question: What is the default URL for a Java EE application running on a glassfish server? I've been googling for a while, and looked through the Glassfish documentation, but I may have overlooked it. Also searched serverFault before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

glassfish will extract a name from the web application project name, underscores (_) will mess it up (talking from experience :-)) and perhaps other characters as well

You can set the name to a name of your choice by setting context root (if you have an EAR it's in the application.xml file), and I highly recommend doing so